# Is there a function check_rhat() in rstan package?

Tags: stan, rstan

In the following page, I find a function `check_rhat()`. However in the R console, there does not exist even if using `rstan:::`.

So, I made a similar function for diagnosis of rhats in my package, but, if there exist some function to evaluate the rhat I want to use it (if it exists).

https://betanalpha.github.io/assets/case_studies/divergences_and_bias.html

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That function comes into the R session via `source("stan-utility.R")` and is defined [here](https://github.com/betanalpha/knitr_case_studies/blob/master/divergences_and_bias/stan_utility.R#L69). It is not in the **rstan** package.

Comment: Thank you, so,..this is not uploaded in the Cran and I cannot use for my package. Thank you !!

Comment: This function is ,...so simple, even if  MCMC chains contains at least one constant chain for some parameter, then the function `check_rhat()` says that  the chain is suspicious. I do not think that the constant MCMC chain does not converge. Or am I wrong ?....

Comment: A Markov chain that is constant is not suspicious; it is definitely invalid.